# TeamCity feature branch artifact dependencies

Tags: teamcity, feature-branch

I have a canary build (BuildA) in TeamCity (10.0.2) that builds master, develop, and all feature/* branches when commits occur.

I'd like to create another build (BuildB) that takes a small set of artifacts from BuildA, and runs FxCop on the files. And I want BuildB to have a Finish Build trigger, so that when BuildA completes for any branch, BuildB will get the artifacts from that branches build and run.

There seem to be some hurdles to setting this up:

1. When I open the "Edit Artifact Dependency" box, I have to specify a "Build branch", which is a logical branch name, not a wildcard or pattern match.  So I don't know how to setup an artifact dependency on all builds coming out of BuildA.
2. The "Finish Build Trigger" has a branch filter, which looks like I can put "+:*" in to catch all branches, but how does that line up with the "Artifact Dependency" branch name value?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just trigger BuildB, which in turn builds BuildA instead.
Then you can get artifacts from that specific build easily.

Comment: BuildB does not have any VCS dependencies, so it does not get triggered on commits, which is how BuildA gets triggered.